# Replace a specific character with another from regex match?

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++11, replace

I am trying to replace `*` with  whenever `\w*\w` pattern is found. Here is what I have

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string text = "Dear Customer, You have made a Debit Card purchase of INR962.00 on 26 Oct. Info.VPS*Brown House. Your Net Available Balance is INR 5,584.58.";

    regex reg("[\w*\w]");
    text = regex_replace(text, reg, " ");
    cout << text << "\n";
}
```

But it replace the `*` with  and `w` with  also.

Output of the above program is

```
Dear Customer, You have made a Debit Card purchase of INR962.00 on 26 Oct. Info.VPS Bro n House. Your Net Available Balance is INR 5,584.58.
```

Comment: `regex reg(R"((\w)\*(?=\w))");` and replace with `"$1 "`

Comment: regex `[ ]` does not mean what you think it means,

Comment: `[\w*\w]` means replace any of the characters `w` or `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
regex reg(R"(([a-zA-Z])\*(?=[a-zA-Z]))");
text = regex_replace(text, reg, "$1 ");
// => Dear Customer, You have made a Debit Card purchase of INR962.00 on 26 Oct. Info.VPS Brown House. Your Net Available Balance is INR 5,584.58.
```

See [C++ online demo](http://ideone.com/cCl9ca)

The `R"(([a-zA-Z])\*(?=[a-zA-Z]))"` is a raw string literal where `\` is treated as a literal `\` symbol, not an escaping symbol for entities like `\n` or `\r`.

The pattern `([a-zA-Z])\*(?=[a-zA-Z])` matches and captures an ASCII letter char (with `([a-zA-Z])`), then matches a `*` (with `\*`) and then requires (does not consume) an ASCII letter char (with `(?=[a-zA-Z])`).

The `$1` is the backreference to the value captured with the `([a-zA-Z])` group.

Comment: Great answer. It also replaces the `*` with ` ` from pattern like `32423*random`, `random*34234` and `323423*43421` which I don't want.

Comment: But you used `\w` yourself. If you need to only match `*` in between *ASCII letters*, use `[a-zA-Z]` instead.